# подсчет количества столбцов в многомерном массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы

Есть матрица чисел (массив, в котором количество столбцов и строк одинаково). Необходимо подсчитать количество столбцов без `0` элементов.
у меня считает только количество нулей.

```
var Matrix = [
    [1, -2, 3, 4],
    [0, 4, 0, 8],
    [7, 0, -7, -45],
    [76, 65, -50, 3]
];
M(Matrix);
function M(){
    var count = 0;
    var countCol = Matrix.length; //общее количество столбцов
    for (var row = 0; row < Matrix.length; row++){
        for (var col = 0; col < Matrix[row].length; col++){
            if (Matrix[row][col] === 0){
                count ++; 
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
    var countWithoutZero = countCol - count;
    console.log(countWithoutZero);
}
```

Comment: а внутренние массивы это строки или столбцы?

Comment: думаю столбцы .

Comment: @Егор, Думаете?)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для случая когда хранятся столбцы можно применить функции [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) и [*every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), либо вместо [*every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) - [*indexOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var Matrix = [
    [1, -2, 3, 4],
    [0, 4, 0, 8],
    [7, 0, -7, -45],
    [76, 65, -50, 3]
];

document.body.innerHTML = Matrix.reduce(function(count, cur){
  return cur.every(function(el){ return el != 0; })? count+1 : count;
},0);

document.body.innerHTML = Matrix.reduce(function(count, cur){
  return count + (~cur.indexOf(0) && 1);
},0);
```

Для случая когда хранятся строки

```js
var Matrix = [
    [1, -2, 3, 4],
    [0, 4, 0, 8],
    [7, 0, -7, -45],
    [76, 65, -50, 3]
];

function m(M){
  var rowCount = M.length;
  if(rowCount == 0) return 0;
  var colCount = M[0].length;
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rowCount; j++){
      if(M[j][i] == 0) break;
    }
    if(j == rowCount) count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}

document.body.innerHTML = m(Matrix);
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно так:

```js
function columnsWithoutZero(m) {
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++) {
        if ( (m.filter(function (v) {return v[i] === 0;})).length ) continue;
        cnt++;
    }
    document.body.textContent = ('Number of columns: ' + cnt);
}
var matrix = [
    [1, -2, 3, 4],
    [0, 4, 0, 8],
    [7, 0, -7, -45],
    [76, 65, -50, 3]
];
columnsWithoutZero(matrix);
```

Comment: спасибо, но что-то тут не так. мне выдает 1, а должно же быть 2! или я все же путаю столбцы и строки?

Comment: @Егор Путаете вы или нет - виднее вам. Я предполагал, что столбцы - это элементы вложенных массивов с одинаковыми индексами. То есть, первый столбец: 1,0,7,76, второй: -2,4,0,65 и т.д.